# Persistir em minha base de dados valores passados por uma DropDown no meu html?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma `dropdownlist` com todos as UF do Brasil. Por exemplo:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ObterUF()
{
     return IncluirSelecioneNoDropDown(new List<SelectListItem>()
     {
                new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Value = "CE",
                    Text = "CE"
                }
     }.AsEnumerable<SelectListItem>());
}
```

Como faço para persistir em minha base de dados o valor passado pela lista no meu html?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma classe para ser o seu *Model* que irá conter as propriedades que você deseja persistir e uma propriedade do tipo lista para o usuário selecionar o UF como essa:

```
public class SeuCadastroViewModel
{
    public SeuCadastroViewModel(IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listaDeUFs)
    {
        ListaUFs = listaDeUFs;
    }

    //Propriedades do cadastro
    public int ID { get; set; }

    //Lista de UFs
    public int IdUFSelecionado { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListaUFs { get; set; }   

}
```

No Controller você pode obter uma lista dos seus UFs e passá-la para o seu *Model*, que por fim irá preencher a lista.

```
public class SeuController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        //Recupera uma lista de UFs
        var listaDeUFs = ObterUF();
        return View(new SeuCadastroViewModel(listaDeUFs));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(SeuCadastroViewModel seuCadastroViewModel)
    {
        //Recupera o UF selecionado e salva no banco de dados
        var uf = ObterUFporId(seuCadastroViewModel.IdUFSelecionado);
        ...
    }
}
```

Já na sua *View* você poderia renderizar o DropDownListFor assim:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdUFSelecionado, Model.ListaUFs)
```